# launch exe with params, but program closes instantly after opening?

Tags: c#, launcher, launching-application

I am writing a client for my gaming community and one of the functions of this client is to launch a game via the client with parameters that will enable our community mod pack on launch.

When I press the button, the game begins to launch and as soon as the program opens (the icon pops up in the task bar), it closes instantly.

Is there something I am missing that is needed to keep the launched exe running?

**Here is my code:**

```
private void btnLaunchGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string armaPath = gameDir+"/Expansion/beta/";
        string filename = Path.Combine(armaPath, "arma2oa.exe");
        string launchParams = "-noSplash -noFilePatching -showScriptErrors \"-name=Meta\" \"-mod=I:/Steam/steamapps/common/Arma 2;expansion;expansion/beta;expansion/beta/expansion;servermods/@HC_DAYZ;servermods/@HC_WEAPONS;servermods/@HC_EXTRAS;servermods/@HC_ACE\"";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, launchParams);
    }//close Game Launch
```

Any ideas is appreciated!

I have a .bat file that will execute the game flawlessly with the launch args listed below, this could possibly help pinpoint the cause of my problem:
http://puu.sh/5CGKk.png (couldn't get code to paste in a readable format).

Comment: Add `form_closing` event in your game and check in it that what could be the problem.. I think the problem is with your game.. or may be with your parameters

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown ?
What does it return ? may be the armaPath, filename and launchParams are not being properly generated ?

Comment: It does not throw any exception that I have found. it appears to launch ok, then once it opens it closes. (arma has a pre-open launch process if you have every played it you know what im talking about).

Comment: @Shaharyar I am not familiar with what that is or how it would be included into this code. I am still pretty new to C# and have only taken 3 college level courses on C# (all of which are leagues below what I am doing with this client).

Comment: @Meta, have you tried looking for some logs of the game? If it doesn't launch without closing immediately, it's probably a crash

Comment: @Andrew, I believe the issue was that there needed to be a working directory set for the exe to stay opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Process`:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "arma2oa.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-noSplash -noFilePatching -showScriptErrors \"-name=Meta\" \"-mod=I:/Steam/steamapps/common/Arma 2;expansion;expansion/beta;expansion/beta/expansion;servermods/@HC_DAYZ;servermods/@HC_WEAPONS;servermods/@HC_EXTRAS;servermods/@HC_ACE\"";
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = gameDir + "/Expansion/beta/";
        process.Start();
```

It may be what exe require working directory to be set. Or it will crash, unable to load resources.

If that doesn't works, then perhaps you need to add

```
            process.WaitForInputIdle();
```

before exiting function running process. I don't know why, but running Acrobat Reader without this wait may sometimes cause a wierd effect: Acrobat is running, but the document, passed via arguments, is not shown. Perhaps something to do with Garbage collector or `Process` itself.

Comment: I have a .bat file that I can use to launch the game with that works great, would including that .bat file possibly give clues to something i could be missing? I added a screenshot of the working .bat file used to launch the game.

Comment: @Meta it's probably because you tried to set the filename as "arma2oa.exe" instead of the full path. Use your original code for the file path: `process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(gameDir+"/Expansion/beta/", "arma2oa.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files\Arma2oa\Arma2oa.exe");
   startInfo.Arguments = "-noSplash -noFilePatching -showScriptErrors \"-name=Meta\" \"-mod=I:/Steam/steamapps/common/Arma 2;expansion;expansion/beta;expansion/beta/expansion;servermods/@HC_DAYZ;servermods/@HC_WEAPONS;servermods/@HC_EXTRAS;servermods/@HC_ACE\"";
   process.StartInfo = startInfo;
   process.Start();
}
```